# Can WebAssembly errors show a line number and file?

Tags: webassembly

Right now my WebAssembly stack traces print the function name for each method in the trace, but not the line number and file. Instead I see something like this after the function name:

`wasm-function[30203]:213`

I swear it used to show the line number and file at some point.

I reviewed that I'm compiling with `-g4`.

EDIT: I'm compiling C++ with the Emscripten compiler. I'm running this in Google Chrome.

Comment: Some context required. Which engine/browser are you using, what language are you compiling, what compiler are you using, do you have source maps enabled?

Comment: Apologies. I'm using Google Chrome and I'm compiling C++ with the emscripten compiler. Yes, I believe I have source maps enabled because that is done by the -g4 compile option: https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-g4